# Re-arranging values in a [1x1] dataframe to [MxN] dataframe in R

Tags: r

Values in the current data frame appears to be-

```
C1
1000|22345|AMERICA|2021-05-03|12:12:12+2220|03330|AUSTRALIA|2021-04-03|12:00:00
```

How do we rearrange it to-

```
 C1    C2       C3           C4          C5         
1000  22345   AMERICA    2021-05-03   12:12:12
2220  03330  AUSTRALIA   2021-04-03   12:00:00
```

### Rules:

The columns are separated using |
The rows are separated using +

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `+` with new line character (`\n`) and read the data with `|` as separator.

```
read.table(text = gsub('+', '\n', df$C1, fixed = TRUE), sep = '|')

#    V1    V2        V3         V4       V5
#1 1000 22345   AMERICA 2021-05-03 12:12:12
#2 2220  3330 AUSTRALIA 2021-04-03 12:00:00
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(C1 = "1000|22345|AMERICA|2021-05-03|12:12:12+2220|03330|AUSTRALIA|2021-04-03|12:00:00"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `separate`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
    separate_rows(C1, sep="\\+") %>% 
    separate(C1, into = str_c('C', 1:5), sep="\\|")
# A tibble: 2 x 5
#  C1    C2    C3        C4         C5      
#  <chr> <chr> <chr>     <chr>      <chr>   
#1 1000  22345 AMERICA   2021-05-03 12:12:12
#2 2220  03330 AUSTRALIA 2021-04-03 12:00:00
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(C1 = "1000|22345|AMERICA|2021-05-03|12:12:12+2220|03330|AUSTRALIA|2021-04-03|12:00:00"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```